# Creating a PDF form, trying to calculate using check marks

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, forms

I'm creating a fillable form in Adobe DC.
I have the following sheet set up:

[image]

I'm trying to set up the total cost field to auto populate with the cost when check marks are made.

I know very little JS, so I'm really struggling on trying to get this variable to populate automatically.

The select checkboxes are:

- selectiPhone
- selectSwipe
- selectMonitor (I would really like to multiply the amount pushed to the total by the amount in the notes field, which is a number field, defaulting to 1
- selectDesktop
- selectLaptop
- selectiPadCell
- selectiPad
- selectPhone

I have tried a code:

```
event.value = 0;
var aEquipment = new Array("iPhone", "Swipe", "Monitor", "Desktop",           "Laptop", "iPadCell", "iPad", "Phone");
for(var i = 0; i < aEquipment.length; i++) {
if(aEquipment[i] != "Monitor") {
  event.value = Number(event.value) + this.getField("Cost" +     aEquipment[i]).value * (this.getField("select" + aEquipment[i]).value != "Off");
  } else {
   event.value = Number(event.value) + this.getField("Cost" +     aEquipment[i]).value * this.getField("Notes" + aEquipment[i]).value *     (this.getField("select" + aEquipment[i]).value != "Off");
  }
}
```

To no success.  I haven't been able to get this to match up and actually add anything to the cost, no matter what I put into the CostX fields.

Comment: Unsure why this got downvoted.   Did I violate something with posting this?

Comment: I guess you didn't show much effort trying to solve the issue yourself, at least you didn't provide evidence of that. It's always a good idea showing what you tried so far.

Comment: Added code to original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is at https://www.dropbox.com/s/tig6bibbj2t6c7q/conditionalSum.pdf?dl=0 - this will allow for a conditional sum to work.